# Phonegap with ChildBrowser Example Code

Tags: android, cordova

Hi Friends I need an example code of phonegap project with ChildBrowser plugin installed.I searched the internet and cant find any please help me.

Comment: which phonegap version you are working now

Comment: Hi,am working on latest phonegap 3.4

Comment: hi did u find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add this inappbrowser cordova plugin into your project.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser